# def main() Invalid Syntax, Dev Server & Terminal

Tags: python, syntax

From terminal:

> ```
> File "index.py", line 41
> def main():
>   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

From App Engine dev server.  I'm running 2.7.3rc2 on Debian:

> ```
> msg = 'invalid syntax'
>       offset = 3
>       print_file_and_line = None
>       text = 'def main():\n'
> ```

Script:

```
def main():   # << here
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: did you forget the shebang line (e.g. #!/usr/bin/python)?

Comment: What's the line right above `def main():`?

Comment: When you get an error, give us the actual error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error is probably being caused by a syntax error higher up in the code, like a missing close paren.

For example the following code will give a SyntaxError in the same place as your code:

```
(
def main():
    pass
```

If you are having a hard time tracking it down, post some of the code that comes earlier.

Comment: same thing here. I missed a closing paranthesis `)` in the last line of the previous method